# Why does my API code return "You are not subscribed to this API." even with the "X-RapidAPI-Key"?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, api-key, rapidapi

I am trying to execute the an API which I found on rapidapi.com.

The url of the API is https://rapidapi.com/sheharyar566/api/random-words5/?utm_source=ANIA-KUBOW&utm_medium=DevRel&utm_campaign=DevRel.

I copied the code from the site which includes the "X-RapidAPI-Key" value when you are logged in.

But when I execute the code on node, I get the message "You are not subscribed to this API."

How do I get it to return the correct result, which is a randomly generated word?

Below is the code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "KEY-GOES-HERE",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "random-words5.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
};

fetch(
    "https://random-words5.p.rapidapi.com/getMultipleRandom?count=5&wordLength=5",
    options
)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

And below is the error message:

> { message: 'You are not subscribed to this API.' }

Comment: Are you subscribed to one of the plans? https://rapidapi.com/sheharyar566/api/random-words5/pricing

Comment: @AndreyBukati It works now. Please add your answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, you are not subscribed to the API. RapidAPI supports 3 tiers of subscriptions:

- Free
- Freemium
- Paid

On free APIs, the subscription will be auto-created on the first call. For freemium and paid, you will need to navigate the `plans` tab and select the right plan for you.
In your case, go to https://rapidapi.com/sheharyar566/api/random-words5/pricing and select one of the plans.